# Надо ли ставить запятую или запятые в уточняющем обороте?

Tags: пунктуация

Знаю, что вопрос глупый, но... Надо ли ставить запятую или запятые в этом уточняющем обороте? Или выделить двумя тире?
Начали мы работу в 2008 году, а уже в следующем году(,) на выставке вооружений ВТТВ–2009(,) демонстрировали образцы изделий из суперрезины: от уплотнительных колец, манжет и прокладок до калош.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При уточнении запятые можно поставить. 
Уточняющий смысл члена предложения может возникнуть в условиях контекста, хотя прямые значения обстоятельственных слов и не указывают на такое соотношение.
Напр.: В этот раз, подле больной матери, ***Султанмурат особенно остро почувствовал запустение жизни без отца (Айтм.) — временно́е значение сочетания в этот раз снимает пространственный оттенок в значении обстоятельства подле больной матери.*** Подобные члены предложения при сохранении своего собственного значения выделения знаками не требуют, ср.: В этот раз подле больной матери Султанмурат особенно остро почувствовал... [Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=419.xuH7yT0CarJgCrZHiWw4weBXAyyC_adKYc5hLqjHNDNQNXET-OySFc-QBquzmFAH41gLOnzS9FIvsVuz8mpp2p6rfDPNbi5cjp2XtbNxzNOJqO0mJ9sGbDf_BFNOa2IyJpRhrPWuhTp1vmEfq-_5rTfiHI1ERc5bGsNtmHyF915ess1upLUMySJ3Vto57sMKJI2juMyv2zf-j9aOJ4UkcsUfxPQ-jiipRs54RiXhg8lUjzUWAQ5zQPusl2WZAm5nJ4bWcHf81G4vI91uNHeJ9Yz1m_EZtXFF_WWB99hCM7dYxTsrPfGy6KfmkN9lRYXSrOulQG_k1NK6t4p412LbvfKD008V4arVV65bHQWjjMpUvpBzOEurKRD4EveG8c5OIfFJ4Ekyxa6qTWl6v_bBQCLk6dfRiA9KIU28y9zlAU6AK6DGZGyLiC60HaGDGZnR3_aKaBjVYmAjEPxD5D7ZS5ElHLY9pgsuKB4DHN3JQTSbIKfvPFqmKFEuHzr_rnlWpaJW9WQQkO8zky9f7bPhPg.11a60940fc89c5afa06211ea9df283d0d78ef7c6&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW9J0KiE5XNXd1-5lCoUJb8Spzg0aAClArkHM-JUIm78SfdmiVJwMGatT1ljJo128hz5kyRDSnXDtDfFk_XZU6np1rt3lxFfQwb7lIki7g1gXWVea1LYWiT0P-2KJU-fAjv-ukJRDVPq-jEF8qO3oQt5IIihuLMQN1ZIHangsAS72ZTYRg4zMQwwDoAqfC6U1M4&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxdVBnSWEtU2RCVVV2V2dsRWd3UFhiTFhLdzZQR2xQUG5Wcm9LUTF0NVlvem90dVRpNHBtV3YxM2hGZmtTSmk4bXRUZy1rT3gwZU0wUUpleVY2WFE0UkE&b64e=2&sign=c9a1be42afbd60c7e73fc2ffb4778e6b&keyno=0&l10n=ru&cts=1408265395129&mc=5.344349179505848)

Comment: Спасибо. С этим справочником тоже сталкивалась. Просто бывает трудно решить, как же все-таки сделать...

Comment: Да, вы правы. Иногда на практике трудно бывает применить то или иное правило.

Comment: Уважаемый Серж! Ваши доводы интересны, но пример неудачный. В приведенном Вами предложении "В этот раз, подле больной матери, Султанмурат особенно остро почувствовал запустение жизни без отца" слова "подле больной матери" вовсе не означают место, где он почувствовал. Смысл их временной: когда он почувствоал? Когда мать болела, когда он находился возле больной матери. Поэтому в приведенном примере обособление уместно.

Comment: Может, мой пример и не совсем удачный, но само предложение, о котором идет речь подходит под это правило.  Я не утверждаю, что запятая обязательна. Я лишь подчеркнул, что при уточнении возможна запятая.

Comment: Запятая возможна. См. Справочник-практикум .Факультативные знаки препинания.Стр.333. Д.Э. Розенталь

Answer (score 3):

"А уже в следующем году" - это обстоятельство времени (когда?)."На выставке вооружений ВТТВ–2009" - обстоятельство места (где?), поэтому никаких запятых не надо. Время нельзя уточнять местом.

Comment: Спасибо, поняла.

Answer (score 1):

"На выставке вооружений ВТТВ–2009"  лучше обособить запятыми.

Не следует подходить к решению задачи формально, так как при необходимости мы можем обособить любое обстоятельство. К тому же в данном случае обстоятельство места косвенным образом соотносится с обстоятельством времени.

Также обособлению способствует значительная распространенность предложения.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Назначение знаков препинания заключается не только в том, чтоб соблюсти правила, но прежде всего в том, чтобы сделать предложение УДОБНЫМ для прочтения и понимания. ОБОСОБЛЕНИЕ обстоятельства как раз и отвечает этим требованиям, так как второе предложение без этого обособления вообще не читается, учитывая его распространенность и необходимость обозначения перечислительной интонации для однородных членов. Надо просто ПРОЧИТАТЬ предложение, чтоб ПОНЯТЬ его структуру.

Answer (score 0):

Согласна с Виктором, что "на выставке вооружений ВТТВ–2009" не стоит выделять запятыми.